# How do I to loop all of contents of list?

Tags: python

```
def create_area_group(sort_area_group):
    for area_name in sort_area_group:
        areas = '\n[{}]\n'.format(area_name)
    return areas 

sort_area_group = ['NewYork', 'London', 'Paris', 'Rome']

print(create_area_group(sort_area_group))
```

That returns out only one string. So how do I extract
all of strings from list?

Also the below code worked that what I expected.
Why 'print' method could it and return method couldn't it?

```
for area_name in sort_area_group:
        areas = '\n[{}]\n'.format(area_name)
        print(areas)
```

Here what it turns out.

```
[NewYork]

[London]

[Paris]

[Rome]
```

I think this is a basic question but I couldn't find same question.

Comment: each time you go around the loop you are changing the value of areas. Such that by the time your loop finishes areas will be set as what ever the last value in the list was. You then return that last value

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I thought 'for' is going to loop until the end of the list so the variable 'areas' receive all of strings from list then return all. But in this case the variable 'areas' just receive each a string and not save for next loop. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

See `help(str.join)` for more information

```
def create_area_group(sort_area_group):
    return "[" + ']\n\n['.join(sort_area_group) + "]"
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't think of that way that using 'join' method.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this function into a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
def create_area_group(sort_area_group):
    for area_name in sort_area_group:
        yield '[{}]'.format(area_name)

#Then iterate over it:
for area in create_area_group(sort_area_group):
    print(area)
```

Or just use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join)

```
print("[{}]".format(']\n\n['.join(sort_area_group)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is that you are changing the value of `areas` at each iteration of you loop, so when you print the result of the `create_area_group` only the last value in `sort_area_group` is going to show up.

Comment: So the variable 'areas' cannot receive multiple strings by loop in this case?